# Is there a solution to creating a perfect hash table for non-finite inputs?

Tags: hash, hashtable

So hash tables are really cool for constant-time lookups of data in sets, but as I understand they are limited by possible hashing collisions which leads to increased small amounts of time-complexity.

It seems to me like any hashing function that supports a non-finite range of inputs is really a heuristic for reducing collision. Are there any absolute limitations to creating a perfect hash table for any range of inputs, or is it just something that no one has figured out yet?

Comment: A perfect hash table for any range of inputs would require infinite space. Obviously, this is infeasible.

Comment: @PhilGabardo interesting to know that. Could you provide proof and perhaps some more details/info?

Comment: Well if this proposed hash table could support an infinite range of inputs, then its hash function would map every unique key to a unique address in memory. Therefore, there would have to be infinite memory addresses to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on what you mean by "any range of inputs."

If your goal is to create a hash function that can take in anything and never produce a collision, then there's no way to do what you're asking. This is a consequence of the pigeonhole principle - if you have n objects that can be hashed, you need at least n distinct outputs for your hash function or you're forced to get at least one hash collision. If there are infinitely many possible input objects, then no finite hash table could be built that will always avoid collisions.

On the other hand, if your goal is to build a hash table where lookups are worst-case O(1) (that is, you only have to look at a fixed number of locations to find any element), then there are many different options available. You could use a [dynamic perfect hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_perfect_hashing) or a [cuckoo hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing), which supports worst-case O(1) lookups and expected O(1) insertions and deletions. These hash tables work by using a variety of different hash functions rather than any one fixed hash function, which helps circumvent the above restriction.

Hope this helps!